# proportional line width ggplot2, in Gantt chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, gantt-chart

I aim to plot line widths proportional to a variable in a data.frame, a topic which has, for example, been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404203/plot-line-width-size-based-on-counts-using-ggplot-or-any-other-method-in-r). 
My application is (although the issue is probably not related to that) within a Gantt chart [adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550341/gantt-charts-with-r) as in:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

MA <- c("A", "B", "C")

dfr <- data.frame(
  name        = factor(MA, levels = MA),
  start.date  = as.Date(c("2012-09-01", "2013-01-01","2014-01-01")),
  end.date    = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2017-12-31","2019-06-30")),
  prozent     = c(1,0.5,0.75)*100
)
mdfr <- melt(dfr, measure.vars = c("start.date", "end.date"))

ggplot(mdfr, aes(value, name)) + geom_line(aes(size = prozent))
```

This yields
[image]
where I do get different line widths, which however do not look proportional to `prozent`.

Is there a way to make the line widths *proportional* to `prozent`?

Comment: does adding `+ scale_size_area()` produce what you are after?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, and please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `+ scale_size_area()`:

```
ggplot(mdfr, aes(value, name)) +
    geom_line(aes(size = prozent)) +
    scale_size_area()
```

[image]